# Is there an analytic solution for linear classifier?

Tags: classification, linear-model

Is it possible to calculate the weight vector anlyticaly for linear classifier? Just like we can do it for linear regression where $w_* = (X^T*X)^{-1} * X^T * y$  is the vector of weights.

Comment: What do you mean by “linear classifier”?

Comment: I second the request for clarification. Do you mean a linear probability model?

Answer (score 1):

There's no “the” linear classifier, but there are different linear classifiers. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_classifier) mentions examples of a few of them.

[Linear probability model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_probability_model) is one of them and the simplest one. It *is* just linear regression fitted to data with binary labels.

Other models like perceptron, logistic regression, LDA, etc don't have closed-form solutions, but we have efficient algorithms for fitting them.